# Partially bold colunm headers with gt

Tags: r, gt

I want to use the R package `gt` and have the table output `ONE` and `TWO` in bold. It looks like you can use markdown syntax inside gt but this doesn't quite work as I'd expect. Any tips?

```
dummy <- tibble(
  `**ONE**, N = 1` = 1,
  `**TWO**, N = 2` = 2
)

dummy %>% 
  gt()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't see anyway to do exactly what you want but this accomplishes it by having a list that maps column names to label name with formatting.

```r
library(tibble)
library(gt)
dummy <- tibble(
"one" = 1,
"two" = 2
)

col_for_list <- list(one = md("**ONE**, N = 1"), two = md("**TWO**, N = 2"))

dummy %>%
gt::gt() %>%
cols_label(.list = col_for_list)
```